# ListView with Custom Adapter in SherlockFragment, Constructor is undefined (can't pass this)

Tags: listview, android-listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-custom-view

I beg of your help as a new java/android programmer.
I'm trying to pass "this" through my custom adapter, to set up a ListView within a SherlockFragment. Unfortunately, I get a an error before compile in my onCreateView, when setting the adapter (new LeatherAdapter(this)) in undefined constructor. Could someone please explain step by step a solution to my problem?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class LeatherTab extends SherlockFragment {

private ListView leather_listview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leather_fragment, container, false); //Fragment Layout inflated
    leather_listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.leather_list); // List is initialized
    leather_listview.setAdapter(new LeatherAdapter(this)); //Custom list adapter passes Context
    return view;
}
}


class SingleRow {

String title;
String description;
int image;

SingleRow(String title, String description, int image) {
    this.title=title;
    this.description=description;
    this.image=image;
}
}


class LeatherAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
Context context;
public LeatherAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
    list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

    Resources res = c.getResources();
    String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.leather_list_titles);
    String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.leather_list_description);
    int[] images = {R.drawable.belt, R.drawable.wallet, R.drawable.coincase};

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        new SingleRow(titles[i], descriptions[i], images[i]);
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.leather_title);
    TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.leather_description);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.leather_icon);


    SingleRow temp = list.get(position);

    title.setText(temp.title);
    description.setText(temp.description);
    image.setImageResource(temp.image);

    return row;//returns the rootView of single_row.xml
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
leather_listview.setAdapter(new LeatherAdapter(this));
```

to

```
leather_listview.setAdapter(new LeatherAdapter(getActivity());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()

`public final Activity getActivity ()`

**Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.**